# How to fix uneven border width after view transformation?

Tags: ios, swift, transformation

Whenever I transform the box, the border widths become uneven.

[image].    [image]

I tried redrawing the frame after each transformation, but the issue still occurs. This is the relevant code:

```
@objc func pinchedView(_ sender:UIPinchGestureRecognizer){
    box.transform = box.transform.scaledBy(x: 1.0, y: sender.scale)
    box.frame = CGRect(x: box.frame.minX, y: box.frame.minY, width: box.frame.width, height: box.frame.height)
    box.layer.borderWidth = 1
    sender.scale = 1
}
```

So how do I maintain a constant border width after transformation?

Comment: Looks like you're scaling the entire `UIView`, which might be stretching the border. Have you tried transforming the height instead?

Comment: Instead of scaling the view, resize it (update its frame). Then it will redraw itself as expected.

Comment: But I use scale so the expansion occurs on both sides and not just the top or bottom. When I update the frame, the x and y coordinates are static.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `transform` to scale a view, that will scale everything, including the border. Instead, you’d just adjust the `frame` of the view.

E.g., if you defined your view’s `frame` directly (and you are not using constraints), then you would:

```
var oldHeight: CGFloat = 0

@objc func handlePinch(_ gesture: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    switch gesture.state {
    case .began:
        oldHeight = subview.frame.height

    case .changed:
        subview.frame = CGRect(x: subview.frame.minX, y: subview.frame.minY, width: subview.frame.width, height: oldHeight * gesture.scale)

    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Or, if you were using constraints, you’d set up and `@IBOutlet` to the height constraint, for example, and then do something like:

```
@IBOutlet var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

var oldHeight: CGFloat = 0

@objc func handlePinch(_ gesture: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    switch gesture.state {
    case .began:
        oldHeight = heightConstraint.constant

    case .changed:
        heightConstraint.constant = oldHeight * gesture.scale

    default:
        break
    }
}
```